# Simple If return in VUE.JS method

Tags: vue.js

Template won't show v-if when method return true.

I can log the username password and the failed attempt in the else section of my login method. If I try to log the loginFailed var I get loginFailed is not defined.

```
<template>
<div class="container-big">
    <div class="container-header">
        <h1>Our Login</h1>
    </div>
    <p  v-if="loginFailed"> 
    Login Failed
    </p>
    <div id="loginContainer" class="container-login">
        <P>{{msg}}</p>
        <input id="login" type="text" placeholder="username" v-model="username" spellcheck="false" >
        <input id="key" type="password" placeholder="password" v-model="password" spellcheck="false" >
    </div>
    <div class="container-signin">
        <button  class="signin" id="go" @click="login()"></button>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Login',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'This is your login',
      password: '',
      username: '', 
      loginFailed: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login () {
      console.log(this.username);
      console.log(this.password);   
     if (this.username !== '' && this.password === 'pass') {
        this.$router.push( { name: 'dashboard', path: '/dashboard' }) }
      else {
        console.log('failed attempt')  
        this.loginFailed === true;
        return this.loginFailed
      }
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

What I want to do is if login failed show 
`<p  v-if="loginFailed"> 
    Login Failed
</p>`

Answer (score 0):

In the `login()` method, you're performing a comparison when you should actually assign a value to the `loginFailed` property:

```js
this.loginFailed === true;
```

Change that line so that it actually assigns `true` to `this.loginFailed`:

```js
this.loginFailed = true;
```

**side note:** You most likely don't need to return anything from `login()` since it's simply dealing with instance properties, you might want to remove this line:

```js
return this.loginFailed
```

Comment: Yeah. I was using comparison instead of setting it true. Thank you